# What does this line of code mean? const {"intl": { formatMessage }, } = this.context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, intl, react-intl

I'm new in react and I'm reading some code i found this line of code:

```
const {intl: { formatMessage }, } = this.context
```

is a const declaration but i don't understand
I know is JS ES6 but i don't understand what is it for?
How can I check the value of this const?

thanks

Comment: Look out for object destructuring.

Comment: it means `const formatMessage = this.context.intl.formatMessage`, check [MDN  Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) for more details

Answer (score 5):

As people already answered. This is object destructuring

Simple example: `const contact = {name: 'John', email: 'john@doe.com'}`

With ES6 you can do `const {email} = contact; //email = contact.email`
In case you want to name the variable differently, it would be:

`const {email: mailbox} = contact //equivalent to mailbox = contact.email;`

Back to the original question: `{intl: { formatMessage }, } = this.context`

=> `{formatMessage} = this.context.intl => formatMessage = this.context.intl.formatMessage`

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have is, actually a representation of the following code,

```
const formatMessage = this.context.intl.formatMessage
```

You can read about object destructuring to know more about it.

Comment: thank you @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that this.context contains a structure similar to this

```
this.context = {
  intl:{
      formatMessage: // This has a value let's say "Hello"
  },
//Other key-value pairs could be contained in the context object }
```

This line of code is a shorthand syntax telling you that only the ***formatMessage*** property which can be found inside "intl" should be retrieved from the large object called **"this.context"**